# How to use all cores available in a nodejs application deployed with docker?

Tags: javascript, node.js, docker

I am a newbie in this and I am trying to learn better ways to improve my production builds for node.js applications.
I read that one can use docker and enjoy the benefit of utilizing all the cores available on the host machine. I would like to know how this can be done when the application is deployed to a hosting platform like `render` host or any other host. Are there codes I need to write in my dockerfile to ensure this before deploying or would the host platform handle that? This is my docker file:

```
FROM node:lts-alpine

WORKDIR /app

COPY package*.json ./ 

COPY backend/package*.josn backend/

RUN npm run install-backend --only=production 

RUN npm run backend-build


COPY backend/src/build /backend/src/build

USER node

CMD ["npm", "production", "--prefix", ]
```

Shared my code already

Comment: Docker just provides a packaging and isolation mechanism for your application; it doesn't automatically make it parallel.  Is your application capable of parallel processing without using container infrastructure?  What would you expect it to do with multiple cores?

Comment: Like I said, I am still learning all of this. But what I read is that the application should be stateless and with multiple core, it can handle more traffic requests. An example was given of when a request is taking longer time to complete maybe due to the nature of the task it is performing, if there is multiple instances of your server, another request coming in can be directed to a less busy instance to handle it. Something similar to what PM2 does with multiple clusters. I don't know if I described this better. I am just looking for a way to implement this and learn from it

Comment: Standard Node has a pretty good callback-based model that lets it make efficient use of a single core.  You could run multiple copies of a Web server application behind a load balancer, and container technologies are one way to do this, but Docker on its own won't make your unmodified application be multi-core.

Comment: will it be best to use PM2 inside the docker build then since it has the inbuilt loadbalancer? I have seen such examples but don't know if that is the best way to go. Or if you have link or resources that I can consume to better understand this.